# Implementing SSO with Simple SAML in an Old .NET 4.0 MVC Application

Tags: federated-identity, ws-federation, simplesamlphp

I need to incorporate Single Sign-on in an existing MVC application. It's a bit long in the tooth now, with only .NET 4.0 libraries. So, a lot of that nice `ClaimsAuthorizationManager/passive redirect` stuff in 4.5 is not available to me.

Can anyone nudge me in the right direction for how I would implement this, dealing with a simple SAML token (which is the token-type of the php identity server that my company has set up)?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could be a good starting point:

**How to Configure an ASP.NET Relying Party Application with Windows Identity Foundation**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg638734.aspx

and

**Configuration for Windows Identity Foundation**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg607699.aspx

and

**The WIF Config Schema**

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vbertocci/2010/05/11/a-hidden-gem-the-wif-config-schema/